# tiddlywiki highlight.js in static mode

Tags: tiddlywiki, highlight.js

I have generated static tiddlers with the command

`generatetiddler`

however the highlight.js is not working (which is expected I guess!?)

How can one "enable" syntax highlighting in static mode?

Answer (score 0):

This was a known limitation. The latest version has fixed this. Please check tiddlywiki.com/prerelease